# How to create a password protected ad-hoc network on Yosemite

Tags: macos, network, wifi, security, ad-hoc

I just tried to create an ad-hoc network on OS X Yosemite and noticed there are no password options. Are they hidden? If so, is there any way to enable them? Is Terminal an option?

Is it possible to create a password protected ad-hoc network on yosemite? If so, how?

Answer (score 12):

You can create a password-protected ad-hoc network by sharing your internet connection. To do so:

1. Go to Apple Menu -> System Preferences
2. Go to Sharing preference pane
3. Select "Internet Sharing"
4. Choose the source port
5. Set your connection to be broadcast over WiFi
6. Click on WiFi options and set a network name and security

While this is a little more involved than just creating the ad-hoc, it will serve the same purpose as well as having the benefit of sharing your connection. At this time, there is no way to add security to an ad-hoc only network on Yosemite.

[Source](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/maclife_101_how_create_adhoc_network)

Comment: Thank you(+1), that's handy to know. Unfortunately I can't share a WiFi connection to WiFi :(

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza True :(

Comment: "WiFi options" is grayed out on Yosemite (2012 MBP Retina), FWIW. Might work on newer macs?

Comment: Works on Mojave too!

Comment: And on Catalina as well.

Answer (score 7):

As a newer answer for making an ad hoc network that works in Mojave without a internet connection, while searching online, I finally found an answer!

Smoooosher's answer only works with an active connection to share.

To create your own "active" network, in terminal run the 2 following commands.

```
sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice Loopback lo0
sudo networksetup -setmanual Loopback 172.20.42.42 255.255.255.255
```

This creates a new network conection that although it looks inactive, it can be shared from the internet sharing preference pane to wifi.

source: https://www.laszlopusztai.net/2016/02/14/creating-a-wi-fi-access-point-on-os-x/

Comment: Doing this made it so my computer refused to reconnect to the wifi when I was done with it. Bad advice.

Comment: You just have to restart the computer and the wifi will reset. It's the only way i have found that actuall does make a shared wifi hotspot without a active connection.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I can create the ad hoc network through sharing and connect to it from an iPad, but can't seem to send UDP data.  Two basic questions: 1. will the IP address given with `-setmanual Loopback` be the host address to send data to? 2. why does the network mask end with 255, not 0, as for manual DHCP? Cheers!

Comment: This command changes your IPv4 loopback address from `127.0.0.1` to whatever you specify, and if you get rid of the service with `sudo networksetup -deletepppoeservice Loopback` it actually gets rid of IPv4 loopback entirely! Whether or not you delete the ad-hoc network, you should run `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1 up` or all sorts of things will break. I do not know if that is a permanent fix though.