Your internet connection cannot be shared because it is protected by 802.1X
(I am a non-tech person, so apologies for my seeming simplistic  language.)
My MacBook Air (M1) (Sonoma 14.5) is connected to my university LAN network. I wanted to share the internet by following these steps:
System Settings -> General -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing.
This takes me to
Share your connection from USB 1-/100/1000 LAN
To device using: (this I set to) WiFi
After this, I get the following warning:

Your internet connection cannot be shared because it is protected by 802.1X. Choose a different network to share or disable Internet Sharing.

How do I fix this problem? My friend is able to share the same intenet from his Windows system without any issue.

Resharing networks can bring them down due to routing errors. Are you certain the university supports this for either windows or macOS? Which choice did you configure for sharing?. Note, the ISP in your case at the bottom is the university. Consider asking them for help if you can’t afford to be banned from that network for a policy violation. Also, can you confirm you connect to the LAN via an ethernet adapter and intend to share that network out with WiFi on either Windows or macOS?

Not directly answering the question, but you could follow the instructions https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208060/how-to-create-a-password-protected-ad-hoc-network-on-yosemite-when-not-connected - This mimics closer to what you can do with Windows.

Depending on what device you wish to share your internet access to, you might be able to accomplish this with a SSH tunnel or a basic VPN. (Although I assume it's most likely a game console type device, so you might be SOL there!)
